# Comunicando aplicação Android com Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

Estou tentando realizar uma implementação para exibir os aparelhos Bluetooth pareados e os conectados ao redor de um celular.
Fiz várias [pesquisas](http://www.klebermota.eti.br/2012/08/26/usando-o-bluetooth-no-android-traducao-da-documentacao-oficial/), achei um [exemplo](https://github.com/jeroqueiroz/BuscaDispBluetooth) e agora estou tentando construir uma implementação minha. O que desejo é construir uma classe chamada Bluetooth a qual possua as seguintes implementações:

Um método para verificar se o Bluetooth do celular está habilitado, caso não, habilita.
Uma lista de dispositivos pareados e conectados.
Um método para conectar com o aparelho Bluetooth.

Sendo assim iniciei o desenvolvimento, chegando ao seguinte código:

```
package br.ufscar.dc.controledepatrimonio.Util.RFID;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

import br.ufscar.dc.controledepatrimonio.R;

public class Bluetooth extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private BluetoothAdapter dispositivo;
    private Activity activity;

    public Bluetooth (Activity activity) {
        dispositivo = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    private void habilitarConexao(Bluetooth bluetooth) {
        if (bluetooth.dispositivo == null) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, R.string.msg_bluetooth_nao_suportado, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
        if (!bluetooth.dispositivo.isEnabled()) {
            Intent i = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            activity.startActivity(i, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    }
}
```

O problema é que a constante REQUEST_ENABLE_BT apresenta o seguinte erro:
"Cannot resolve symbol 'REQUEST_ENABLE_BT'"
Até encontrei um [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188277/error-checking-if-bluetooth-is-enabled-in-android-request-enable-bt-cannot-be-r) sobre isso, e fiz o que é comentado lá, mas ocorre outro erro:
"Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'int'. required: 'android.os.Bundle'"

Gostaria de saber o por que disso. Visto que se eu fizer a mesma codificação em uma Activity ela funciona normalmente.
Agradeço desde já pela ajuda!!

Answer (score 0):

Pessoal cheguei a uma solução.
Fiz da seguinte forma:

```
package br.ufscar.dc.controledepatrimonio.Util.RFID;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

import br.ufscar.dc.controledepatrimonio.R;

public class Bluetooth extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private BluetoothAdapter dispositivo;

    public BluetoothAdapter getDispositivo() {
        return dispositivo;
    }

    public enum Estado {
        LIGADO, DESLIGADO, NAO_COMPATIVEL;
    }

    public Bluetooth () {
        dispositivo = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    }

    public Estado verificarEstado() {
        if (dispositivo == null) {
            return Estado.NAO_COMPATIVEL;
        }
        if (!dispositivo.isEnabled()) {
            return Estado.DESLIGADO;
        }

        return Estado.LIGADO;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    }

}
```

Com isso eu retorno o estado do Bluetooth para minha Activity e ela fica responsável por ativar ou não o serviço.
Vou continuar a implementação dos outros métodos!